# How to re-instate emails to Thunderbird from a profile backup?

Tags: email, thunderbird

I have had to reinstall Windows 7. I saved the email folder `\AppData\Roaming\Thunderbird\Profiles\yg3frwjm.default` before doing so.

Now, how do I integrate the mails in this folder to newly created email accounts?

Answer (score 1):

It's covered in [this extensive FAQ](http://kb.mozillazine.org/Thunderbird_:_FAQs_:_Changing_Profile_Folder_Location) on the mozillazine site.

Misread, so you have a new profile and want to copy the old stuff in?  Same document, but different section, [specific link](http://kb.mozillazine.org/Thunderbird_:_FAQs_:_Changing_Profile_Folder_Location#Create_a_new_profile_and_migrate_your_old_data).

Which [eventually goes here](http://kb.mozillazine.org/Transferring_data_to_a_new_profile_-_Thunderbird).

Which says,

> The simplest way to migrate your mail is to copy Mail and ImapMail
>   (and their sub directories) to the top directory in the new profile,
>   overwriting the existing ones. See Empty folders if it doesn't work.
>
> However, the safest way is to use the ImportExportTools extension to
>   import whatever folders you want to keep. When you run the menu
>   command, it gives you the option of selecting a directory and having
>   it find and select all of the folders in that directory and its
>   subdirectories. See Importing folders for how to install and use that
>   extension.